# Disabling/postponing timer jobs programmatically

Tags: user-profile, timer-jobs, user-profile-service, activity-feed

I wrote a utility that sync's our Oracle HR database of employees into SharePoint profiles. It loads all 150,000 employees from Oracle into an array, for each employee it retrieves or creates a SharePoint profile, updates fields from that Oracle source and commits changes into SharePoint User profile, all using SharePoint API.

The problem is - it's very slow. Updating 150,000 profiles took almost 3 days and according to the logs it takes 3-6 seconds to simply commit changes into SharePoint for a single user.

I started up a SQL Profiler and what I see is - for each inserted/updated user there are hundreds of stored procs called for Activity Feeds (updating colleagues feeds, I guess) and some User Profile timer jobs as well. No surprise it's so slow.

Now the question - is there a way to diagrammatically disable/postpone activity feed sync and user profile sync jobs during the run of the utility. I haven't found how to do that and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a PowerShell package that manages [SharePoint PowerShell Timer Jobs](http://ikarstein.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/sharepoint-powershell-timer-jobs-run-powershell-scripts-in-sharepoint-timer-service-context/). But I think there's a more fundamental performance issue that needs to be addressed - you may want to follow up on this recent post - [SharePoint 2010 User Profile Import Performance Optimization](http://blogs.technet.com/b/balasm/archive/2012/05/18/sharepoint-2010-user-profile-import-performance-optimization.aspx).

Another post that may prove helpful - [Best practices for people and profiles (SharePoint Server 2010).](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh377942.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if disabling the timer jobs would solve this issue, but you can check this [blog](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/03/17/enumerating-timer-jobs-for-service-applications-and-a-new-way-of-forcing-the-immediate-execution-of-a-timer-job-from-code/) about getting timer job reference. SPJobDefinition.IsDisabled = true, should disable the timer job.